# Prove that if any two elements of prime power orders commute in a finite group G, then G is Abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

i.e. If $x,y \in G$ such that $ord(x)=p$ and $ord(y)=q$, where $p,q$ are prime, then $xy=yx$. Show this implies $G$ is Abelian.

None of my attempts have been successful, so any hint would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it prime-power order, as in title, or prime order, as in your question text?

Comment: The questions is exactly phrased as: “Let G be a finite group such that any two elements that have prime power orders commute. Show G is Abelian.” I took it to mean what I typed in the question text. Could it possibly mean something else?

Comment: "prime power" is not the same as "prime".

Comment: Oh, I see now. I was thinking exponents. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x,y\in G$, suppose that $ord(x)=m, ord(y)=n$, write $m=pm_1, n=qn_1$ where $p,q$ are prime, $ord(x^{m_1})=p, ord(y^{n_1})=q$ implies that $x^{m_1}$ commutes with $y^{n_1}$. If $m_1=n_1=1$ done, if not we apply agian the previous step.